Orthogonal projection of a complex valued matrix onto the space of Hermitian matrices
It is well known that any real matrix $A$ can be decomposed as the sum of a symmetric and a skew-symmetric matrix as follows:
$$
A= \frac{A+A^T}2+\frac{A-A^T}2.
$$
The decomposition is orthogonal, meaning that $\langle B,\frac{A-A^T}2\rangle=0$ for all symmetric matrices $B$. However, the same derivation would not work for the similar decomposition for a complex matrix:
$$
A= \frac{A+A^H}2+\frac{A-A^H}2.
$$
In other words, $\langle B,\frac{A-A^H}2\rangle\neq 0$ in general for a Hermitian matrix $B$.
So the question is:

Is there a similar decomposition or projection for complex valued matrices such that $A$ can be written as $X+Y$ with $X$ being Hermitian and $Y$ satisfying $\langle Y,B\rangle=0$ for all Hermitian matrices $B$?
A related question: is there an analytical solution for the closest Hermitian matrix to an arbitrary complex valued matrix $A$?


The Hermitian matrices aren't a complex subspace, so I don't think we can expect any kind of projection onto them.

makes sense. Thanks! What about the second question: is there an analytical solution for the closet Hermitian matrix?

I think you can just regard everything as real vector spaces and then use the orthogonal projection, although I'm not sure.

Wait, on complex matrices the definition of the inner product is different: $<A,B>=Tr(A^HB)$, and using it then the above decomposition is still orthogonal

I have been using this definition and could not make it work. Also I did not find any literature on it. I appreciate if you share your proof; good to see where I missed.

A skew-Hermitian matrix is $i$ times a Hermitian matrix. Therefore the answer to your first question is ‘no’.
More specifically, let $H=i\frac{B-B^H}{2}$. Then $H$ is Hermitian. If $\langle Y, \frac{B-B^H}{2}\rangle=0$ for every matrix $B$, we will also have $\langle Y,H\rangle=0$ for every Hermitian matrix $H$. In particular, $\langle Y, \frac{B+B^H}{2}\rangle=0$ for every matrix $B$. It follows that $\langle Y,B\rangle=\langle Y, \frac{B-B^H}{2}\rangle+\langle Y, \frac{B+B^H}{2}\rangle=0$ for every matrix $B$. Hence $Y$ is necessarily zero.
To find the closest (in Frobenius norm) Hermitian matrix to $A$, let $X$ and $Y$ be respectively the real and imaginary parts of $A$. Now consider a Hermitian matrix with real part $S$ and imaginary part $W$. Since $S+iW$ is Hermitian, $S$ must be symmetric and $W$ must be skew-symmetric. Hence the problem boils down to minimising
$$
\|(X+iY)-(S+iW)\|_F^2=\|X-S\|_F^2+\|Y-W\|_F^2
$$
where $S$ is symmetric and $W$ is skew-symmetric. Clearly the answer is given by $S=\frac{X+X^T}{2}$ and $W=\frac{Y-Y^T}{2}$. In other words, the Hermitian you look for is $S+iW=\frac{(X+iY)+(X-iY)^T}{2}=\frac{A+A^H}{2}$, the Hermitian part of $A$.
Alternatively, recall that a complex matrix $A=X+iY$ can be ‘realified’ to a block matrix $M=\pmatrix{X&Y\\ -Y&X}$, where $\|A\|_F^2=2\|M\|_F^2$ and $A$ is Hermitian if and only if $M$ is symmetric. So, finding the closest Hermitian matrix to $A$ is equivalent to finding the closest symmetric matrix to $M$. The minimiser is clearly the symmetric part of $M$, which, when ‘complexified’, becomes the Hermitian part of $A$.

Fantastic answer. Thanks!
